# GitHub GraphQL keeps returning POST https://api.github.com/graphql 401 error

Tags: github, graphql

I have been trying for hours to fetch the data of some of my repositories but I keep getting this error
'POST https://api.github.com/graphql 401'

My Code

```
const githubData = {
  token: "my token",
  username: "mikechibuzor",
};

const body = {
  query: `query { 
  user(login: "mikechibuzor"){
    bio,
    avatarUrl,
    repositories(first: 20, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}){
      nodes{
        name,
        description,
        forkCount,
        languages(first: 100){
          nodes{
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}`,
};

const baseUrl = "https://api.github.com/graphql";
const headers = {
  'Authorization': 'bearer ' + githubData.token,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

fetch(baseUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  Headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  mode: "cors",
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data.data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
```

What am i not doing right?

Comment: I'm gonna assume you now what [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) means. Maybe have a look at the documentation regarding authentication - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication

Comment: okay. I will do that now. Thank you.

Comment: I just did. the Doc tells me that a '401' error occurs when validating with an invalid credentials and it further went on to say ..."After detecting several requests with invalid credentials within a short period, the API will temporarily reject all authentication attempts for that user (including ones with valid credentials) with 403 Forbidden:"

I guess this is what is happening... I'm not sure

Comment: Just a guess but should the header for _Authorization_  be preceded by **token** and not **bearer**?

Comment: No. and I did not put token before bearer.
```'Authorization: 'bearer '+ token(githubData.token),```

Comment: Yeah but if I understand: `$ curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com` correctly, you should use `token` and not `bearer` as _prefix_?

Comment: I just did.... still the same. it's getting frustrating.
Thank you for trying to help

Comment: I would recommend using curl or postman to get the incantation right, then program what you know works

Comment: ... and check network request details - does it contain right headers? I doubt ... fetch options has `headers` prop, not `Headers` ... search for better examples/tutorials

Comment: I have. I had a friend test it for me and it works fine on postman.
The issue lies some where in my code, maybe I am missing out a prefix, or something.

Comment: code results in request ... still compare (show it!) detaily network request headers with postman

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a typo – try the following:

```js
fetch(baseUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  // lowercase 'h' for headers
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  mode: "cors",
})
// ...
```

In case that still doesn't work check your **scopes** for your access token. GitHub gives you detailed control about what kind of actions you want to allow with a specific token and what not.

Comment: Didn't work.
I even tried fetching it with axios, now I am thinking the error should lie somewhere in the scopes.
But I checked all fields when generating the token, gave all permissions to my token

Comment: That is weird, before I answered, I actually copied your code added a first line `const fetch = require("node-fetch");`, replaced githubdata with my own and wrote "headers" as lowercase and it works as expected when I run it via `$ node code.js`